# Why is my header starting so low?

Tags: html, css

It is beginning like 20px from the top and not aligned with the top. If i do margin-top: -15px; then everything moves with it like the text  and it looks off, the text will be more to the top . Here is my css code:

```
body {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;    
}

header, h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: CGF Locust Resistance;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: lightgray;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px black;



}

header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #b3b3b3;
    background-image: url(omen.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}

nav {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #b3b3b3;

}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    font-family: CGF Locust Resistance;
    font-size: 12.5px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Gears of War</title>
    </head>

    <header>
        <h1>GEARS OF WAR</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Gears of War <span class="red">1</span></li>
            <li>Gears of War <span class="red">2</span></li>
            <li>Gears of War <span class="red">3</span></li>
            <li>Gears of War <span class="red">Judgment</span></li>
            <li>Gears of War <span class="red">4</span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <body>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that this is suppose to apply to?

Comment: set `margin: 0` on `body`?

Comment: Take some time to learn Chrome DevTools if you can (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en), it would have made it easier for you to see that that space is created by the margin on `h1` as Wim said.

Comment: Although now the text isnt vertically centered in the header, its more near to the top of the screen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set margin: 0 to h1. you can add padding to it for styling.